# Take a string , evaluate it and find if there is a number and repeat part of string that number of times?

Tags: javascript

I was writing code and came into this problem,
You have a specific string which is in this form:

```
 d ae2 n s
```

now we have to decode this in a specific way,

1. Split it into different parts by spaces to make an array like ["d","ae2","n","s"]
2. Evaluate each element of the array and find out if there is a number in it.
3. If there is a number then repeat the string the number of times.
4. Add it into the array and continue.
   So the output array should be

```
["d","ae","ae","n","s"]
```

I have already tried a lot but got nothing

I have used this code earlier but it ends on the second string:

```
var str = "d ae2 n s"
var res = str.split(" ");
alert(res.length);
for(var x = 0; x < res.length; x++ ){
  var std = res[x];
  var fun = checkNum(std);
  if(fun === true){
   var numbers = str.match(/\d+/g).map(Number);
    var index = res.indexOf(std);
   var result =  std.replace(/[0-9]/g, '');
    var res2 = result.repeat(numbers);
   res[index] = res2;
  }
  else{
    continue;
  }

 for(var i = 0; i < res.length; i++ ){
   console.log(res[x]);
 }
}
function checkNum(t){ 
return /\d/.test(t);
}
// I am a terible coder :/
```

expected input :  d ae2 n s

expected output : ["d","ae","ae","n","s"]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [`fill()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) and [`flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) methods and

**regex replace**

- `/[^0-9]/` - all non numerical chars
- `/[0-9]/` - all numerical chars

```js
var str = 'd ae2 n s'

var res = str
  .split(' ')
  .flatMap(i =>
    Array(+i.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '') || 1)
    .fill(i.replace(/[0-9]/g, ''))
  )

console.log(res)
```

Comment: High "neat" level! Cool

Answer (score 1):

You can simply loop over your array and populate an other array that will hold your result after checking for a number :

```js
const results = [];
"d ae2 n s".split(' ').forEach(token => {
  const match = token.match(/\d+/);
  if (match) {
    const newStr = token.split(/\d/)[0];
    for (let i = 0; i < match[0]; i++) {
      results.push(newStr);
    }
  } else {
    results.push(token)
  }
})

console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check Seblor's answer for optimized logic. I have modified your code so that it will be easy for you to understand where you went wrong while doing this. I have added comments to your code where I have changed things:

```
var str = "d ae2 n s"
var res = str.split(" ");

// create a variable to store the output.
var output = [];
for(var x = 0; x < res.length; x++ ){
  var std = res[x];
  var fun = checkNum(std);
  if(fun === true){

    // map returns an array, so take the first element, it will be your number.
   var numbers = str.match(/\d+/g).map(Number)[0];
    var index = res.indexOf(std);
    var result =  std.replace(/[0-9]/g, '');

    // instead of doing the repeat and updating the current index,
    // push the result, i.e. the current string to be repeated "numbers" times into
    // the output array.
    for (var i = 0; i < numbers; i++) {
      output.push(result)
    }
  }
  else{

    // if does not contain any number, push the current item to ouput
    output.push (std);
    continue;
  }
}
function checkNum(t){ 
return /\d/.test(t);
}
console.log(output);
```

Comment: Always good to see someone reworking OP code to make him understand what was wrong

Comment: Thanks :) I agree. I think it gives insight and perhaps encourages people to build logic. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```js
const str1 = 'd ae2 n s';
const str2 = 'e d aefg4 m n s';
const regex = /\d+/;
const getResult = input => input.split(' ').reduce((a, c) => { 
  const n = c.match(regex);
  return n 
    ? [...a.concat(c.replace(n, ' ').repeat(n).trim().split(' '))]
    : [...a, c];
}, []);

console.log(getResult(str1));
console.log(getResult(str2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with following:

```
let str = "d ae2 n s"
let split = str.split(" ")
let rx = new RegExp("[0-9]")
let res = [];
split.forEach(s => {
  if(rx.exec(s) !== null) {
    let rxResult = rx.exec(s)
    let count = rxResult[0];
    let matchIdx = rxResult[1];
    for(let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      res.push(s.replace(count, ""))
    }
  } else {
    res.push(s);
  }
})
```

Comment: People should not use `var` anymore. It's considered bad practice since ECMAScript 2015.

Comment: Agree, switched to `let`'s. However, for instance Douglas Crockford claims, that `var` is perfectly fine, if you know what you are doing :)

Comment: Yes, `var` can still be 'fine', but the use cases where it is actually useful are nearly non-existant. From what I could find, what Douglas Crockford said was : "var might possibly still be useful in an extreme case like machine-generated code, but I’m stretching hard there." So `var` should not be in any StackOverflow answer, IMHO. Thank you for editing your answer :)

Comment: And thanks for productive discussion on `var`s and `let`s :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the Array prototype `reduce` and `filter`

```js
const input = 'd ae2 n s';
const output = input.split(' ').reduce((memory, current) => {
  const numberIndex = current.split('').findIndex(c => !isNaN(c));
  const newCurrent = current.split('').filter((_, index) => index !== numberIndex).join('');
  
  if(numberIndex !== -1) {
    for(let i = 0; i < parseInt(current[numberIndex]); i++) {
      memory.push(newCurrent);
    }
  } else {
    memory.push(current);
  }
  
  return memory;
}, []);

console.log(output);
```

Hope this helped